Existence of an NDA prohibited to let any prospective employer
I've been advised by my legal advocates who signed my NDA on my behalf not to discuss the circumstances of my termination or the existence of the settlement with anyone.
If I don't disclose this to the prospective employer because I am bound by enforceable agreement and confidentiality, would I be seen as misleading or dishonest and submit in reasons for leaving sections?

As with so many things, this depends on culture, where you live, etc.

It would very strongly depend on the terms in your settlement agreement.

You have answered your own question:
"I've been advised by my legal advocates not to discuss the circumstances of my termination due to an NDA"
Nothing more, nothing less.
That is not being dishonest or misleading.

This usually goes like this: "I cannot discuss the circumstances of me leaving X", and the irony is that everyone instantly understands that some almost-crime happened and the person saying it was paid off to keep it hush.

I have received settlements from some 100% reputable companies. In the UK, there is an amount X that the company needs to pay if they want to stop employing you during the notice period, and they often pay 2X or 3X to get a paper that you have no right to sue them etc. etc. etc. That's absolutely normal here. (If you think you have reason to sue them, the settlement automatically goes down to X. So if they hadn't paid your last three month expenses, you wouldn't sue but keep the larger settlement).

My only nitpick with this answer is that an NDA might (purport to) prohibit disclosure of its existence. So a person subject to NDA might say something like, "I've been advised by my legal advocates not to discuss the circumstances of my termination," or "For legal reasons, my legal advocates advised me that I must not discuss the circumstances of my termination."

Tricky.  The answer suggested by @TheDemonLord

"I've been advised by my legal advocates not to discuss the circumstances of my termination due to an NDA"

is certainly a professional and correct answer.
But here is the problem: you tell your prospective employer that you were in legal conflict with your previous employer. Legal conflict often means that someone screwed up badly. Could have been the company, could have been you (I have seen both) and the new employer has no way of knowing where in that spectrum your case is. From their point of that's a significant risk. Why take it, if there are other suitable candidates in the pipeline?
Yes, that's frustrating and unfair, but if you put yourself into an employer's shoes it makes sense. If you mention a massive problem but can't elaborate what it was, they will have to make their own assumptions and chances these assumptions are worse (for you) than what actually happened.
I think it may be better to stay clear of the legal aspects. Focus on other points that are still correct:

Not a good cultural fit because ..., slow to promote or bad career outlook, .. below market compensation, ... family/personal life changes, ... want to learn something new ...

These are all perfectly normal and acceptable reasons. Do NOT lie, just one or a few that actually fit your situation and flesh them out a bit in case someone starts to follow up in more detail.
If you want to be super safe, have your lawyer look over potential answer to make sure they are in compliance with your NDA.

What I would do is to answer by not answering.

I'm not allowed to discuss the circumstances of me leaving the company due to an NDA. I also cannot confirm nor deny my reception of any kind of settlement.

You did not breach the NDA, and the employer did not get any information protected by the NDA.
But double check if there's a clause that hides even the existence of the NDA itself.
